# failed uploading image // Object not found

Tags: php

I have been trying to upload an image and has it shown after pressing submit button using PHP. it gave me the error below:

[image]

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23

Someone please help me to fix this. I  have no idea where the problem is. Appreciate it!
This is what I have been trying to do:
[image]

```
echo <<<_END
<html><head><title>PHP from Upload</title></head><body>
<form method = 'POST' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form.data'>
Select a JPG, GIF, PNG or TIF File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10'>
<input type='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
_END;

if ($_FILES){
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

    switch($_FILES['filename']['name']){
        case 'image/jpeg': $ext = 'jpg'; break;
        case 'image/gif': $ext = 'gif'; break;
        case 'image/png': $ext = 'png'; break;
        case 'image/tiff': $ext = 'tif'; break;
        default: $ext = ''; break;
    }
    if ($ext){
        $n = "image.$ext";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $n);
        echo "<img src='$n'>";
    }
    else echo "'$name' is not an accepted image file";
}
else echo "No image has been uploaded";
echo "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to change this line …

```
switch($_FILES['filename']['name']){
```

… to this

```
switch($_FILES['filename']['type']){
```

otherwise `$ext` will always be `''` which means that this statement …

```
if ($ext){
```

… will always be `false`. Which is why you will always see …

```
else echo "'$name' is not an accepted image file";
```

Comment: I had also change name to type as well, it is still giving me the same error page. Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method = 'POST' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form.data'>
```

should be

```
<form method = 'POST' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

specifically the enctype should be "multipart/form-data"

Comment: I had changed it to -, but it still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to submit the form and process it with the same page? i.e. upload.php.

You can remove the action tag from the form if you are and it will submit the form to itself.

So

```
<form method = 'POST' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

could be

```
<form method = 'POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```